# Invertibility Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a square matrix that satisfies $A^2=A$. Show that $(I-A)^2=I-A$ and $2A-I$ is invertible and its own inverse.

$(I-A)^2$

$=I^2-2A+A^2$

=$I-2A+A^2$

=$I-2A+A$

$=I-A$

Not sure how to show invertibility for 2A-I, I know you need to show $AA^{-1}=I$ to show invertibility but not sure how to get there.

Comment: You just need to specify the inverse (and you have even been told what that should be).

Comment: Hint. Square $2A-1$.

Comment: since $A^2 = A,$ eigenvalues of $A$ are $0, 1$ and the eigenvalues of $2A-I$ are $-1,1.$ therefore $2A-I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(2A-I)(2A-I)=4A^{2}-4A+I=4(A^{2}-A)+I
$$
Since $A^{2}=A$ we have that
$$
(2A-I)(2A-I)=I,
$$
and therefore $(2A-I)$ is invertible, because it is its own inverse.